# Issue with Conditional Rendering in React Custom Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I'm facing an issue with conditional rendering in a custom component in my React application. I've been working on creating a custom component for conditional rendering that renders content only when a specific condition is met. Here's the code I have so far

```js
import React from 'react';

function ConditionalRenderComponent({ condition, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {condition && children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ConditionalRenderComponent;
```

While using this custom component, I noticed that the content passed through the `children` prop is being accessed and executed even when the `condition` is `false`. This behavior is different from when I directly use `condition && <div></div>` without a custom component, which correctly prevents the content from being accessed when the condition is `false`.

**Here's how I'm using the custom component:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ConditionalRenderComponent from './ConditionalRenderComponent';

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const isLoggedIn = userData !== null;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUserData({
        username: 'john_doe',
        email: 'john@example.com'
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to My App</h1>
      <ConditionalRenderComponent condition={isLoggedIn}>
        <div>
          <p>Hello, {userData.username}!</p>
          <p>Your email: {userData.email}</p>
        </div>
      </ConditionalRenderComponent>
      {!isLoggedIn && <p>Please log in to access user data.</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the example above, the `userData` is initially `null` and later populated with data retrieved from the server. The `isLoggedIn` condition depends on whether the `userData` is populated.

However, even when the `isLoggedIn` condition is `false` (before the data is fetched), the content inside the `ConditionalRenderComponent` still tries to access and display the `userData`. This leads to the error message: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')".

**Comparison with standard conditional rendering:**

Below is a comparison of the behavior using the standard `condition && <div></div>` approach:

```js
// Standard conditional rendering
{isLoggedIn && (
  <div>
    <p>Hello, {userData.username}!</p>
    <p>Your email: {userData.email}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

As shown in the above code, using the standard approach correctly prevents accessing the `userData` values when the condition is `false`.

I'm not sure why this difference in behavior is occurring when using a custom component with the `children` prop. I've tried debugging and searching for solutions, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

I'd really appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this behavior might be happening and how I can modify the custom component to achieve the expected conditional rendering behavior using the `children` prop.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The problem is that the children are evaluated *before* being passed to the component. The are **not** inert. You need to move the conditional stuff *inside the definition* of the component that checks that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why it happens?

So I think the reason it happens is because, in the `ConditionalRenderComponent` component, the children are passed to it as a property (like arguments to a function). JSX expressions are evaluated as arguments to functions.

This means that even if the `condition` is false, the `children` are still evaluated before being passed to the `ConditionalRenderComponent` function.

### Example to understand easily

You are giving a child a `PlayStation` (in your left hand) and `Math paper marks` (in your right hand) and saying that if he/she scores more than 90/100, he/she will get the PlayStation.

Since the child already can see the PlayStation in your left hand (passing `children` as a JSX Expression), he/she already starts using without even checking for the condition.

Now if you close your fist, synonymous to passing the `children` as a function, he/she can't evalute what is in the left hand before checking if the condition is true in your right hand.

### Solution

We modify our custom component by using a function as a child instead of directly rendering the `children` within the component. This way, you can ensure that the evaluation of the `children` only happens if the `condition` is true.

#### Changes to ConditionalRenderComponent

```
function ConditionalRenderComponent({ condition, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {condition && children()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Changes to rendering ConditionalRenderComponent

```
<ConditionalRenderComponent condition={isLoggedIn}>
        {() => (
          <div>
            <p>Hello, {userData.username}!</p>
            <p>Your email: {userData.email}</p>
          </div>
        )}
</ConditionalRenderComponent>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend creating a component for conditional rendering, but if you want to do it, you can use the render prop pattern so that the function is called only when the condition is true. This prevents the expressions from getting evaluated right away.

```
function If({ condition, render }) {
  if (!condition) return null;

  return render();
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    wait(1000).then(() => {
      setState({ hello: "world" });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <If condition={Boolean(state)} render={() => <p>{state.hello}</p>} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit snowy-framework-pv2ptp]

Comment: Thanks for your help! The solution is working perfectly. I'm curious to know if there's another approach using the `children` prop instead of passing render props. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @sanbinary Yes, you can pass a function as `children` and call it the same way render is called (`children()`).